# Mvc Partial LogIn Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, authentication

I am new with MVC, and I want to implement partial LogIn which I can use in several views. But I have one issue which I cannot understand.

So in /views/shared/_LogOnPartial.cshtml I have next code:

```
@using netlek.ViewModels.Account
@model LogOnModel
<div class="widget-main padding-6">
     @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = @Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }))
     {
         @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Oops, that didn't work.", new Dictionary<string, object>() { })
         <div class="loginctr">
             <fieldset class="account">

                 <label class="block clearfix">
                      <span class="input-icon input-icon-right">
                           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { placeholder = "Username / Email" })
                       </span>
                       <span class="block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)</span>
                  </label>

                  <label class="block clearfix">
                        <span class="input-icon input-icon-right">
                              @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { placeholder = "Password" })
                        </span>
                        <span class="block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)</span>
                  </label>  

                  <div class="fl">
                     <input type="submit" value="Log On" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" style="margin: 20px 0;" />
                  </div>

            </fieldset>
        </div>
    }

</div>
```

So this is simple Post Form that Posts to /Account/LogOn (AccountController):

```
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        model.NoCcRequired = !ApplicationSettings.RequireCcUpfront;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                TrackingTasks.SetUserAction(MvcApplication.DbSession, model.UserName, TrackingActionType.LoggedIn, TrackingPropertyType.LastLoginDate, DateTime.UtcNow);

                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);

                if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                    && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                {
                    return this.RedirectToFirstPage(model.UserName, returnUrl);
                }

                return this.RedirectToFirstPage(model.UserName, string.Empty);
            }

            var user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);

            if (user != null && user.IsLockedOut)
            {
               ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "To protect your account, you have been locked out due to too many failed login attempts. Please contact support.");

               return this.View(model);
             }

            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return this.View(model);
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this Partial Login in two different pages (two view models):

/views/Account/LogOn.cshtml (standard LogOn page):

```
@using netlek.ViewModels.Account
@model LogOnModel
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_NoHeaderLayout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Log On";
}

//SOME HTML BEFORE

<div class="span4 align-left">
    @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
</div>

//SOME HTML AFTER
```

And I want to use it in another page (another view)

/views/Extension/LogOn.cshtml:

```
@using netlek.ViewModels.Account
@model LogOnModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_NoHeaderLayout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Log On";
}

<div id="logon-wrap" class="span4">
    @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
</div>
```

The issue which i have is that If I visit second LogOn page (Extension/LogOn), and submit login form without username and password so it fails. It hit method LogOn() in AccountController and because it fails i returns return this.View(model); and it redirects me to standard LogOn page (/Account/LogOn).

So if I visit second page where I have this partial LogOn:

/External/LogOn and I hit LogIn button without any details it fails and redirect me to /Account/LogOn page, but I want to stay on the same page /External/LogOn.

I understand why this is happening, because it's hitting AccountControler.LogOn() and it returns View(model), it returns "View/Account/LogOn.cshtml". But I don't know how to fix/implement this properly.

So I want this partial login to use in several views and in case it fails to return view from which I submited the form not always /Account/LogOn view.

Comment: You would be better of having 2 separate partial views posting to separate methods, but you could always add a route parameter or hidden input for the view name so that you could use `return .View(viewName, model);`

Comment: I don't necessary need 2 separate partial views posting to seperate methods. I can have one partial posting to separate methods, with just using Html.BeginForm(), without specifily controller and method. But I would really like to avoid 2 methods. And don't know how I can get it with adding a route parameter.

Comment: Not necessarily recommending this, but inside your Controllers, you also have access to the `Request` object in which you could get `AbsolutePath` and use that to determine which View to return.

Comment: All a bit ugly, but you could add a property `string ReturnViewName` to your `LogOnModel` that you populate in the GET methods and then generate a hidden input so that its posted back and then `return View(model.ReturnViewName, model);

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is inherit your ExternalController class from AccountController, and modify the partial view to post to the LogOn action. Now as the LogOn method lives in the ExternalController class as well, returning the `View(model)` returns the Logon View of External. (You are mixing Extension and External, but I assume they are the same).

Some other remarks of your code to make them more secure: check if returnUrl is in your domain, and include an anti-forgerytoken to prevent your site against CSRF attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with change your controller parameters like this,

```
public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl, string view = string.Empty)
{
  // Your code here and then write below condition

  if(view == "External")
     return RedirectToAction("Extension/LogOn");
  else
     return View(model);

}
```

Now from parent view call partial view like below;

/views/Account/LogOn.cshtml (standard LogOn page):

```
@using netlek.ViewModels.Account
    @model LogOnModel
    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_NoHeaderLayout.cshtml";
        ViewBag.Title = "Log On";
    }

    //SOME HTML BEFORE

    <div id="LogOn" class="span4 align-left">
       // @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
    </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#LogOn").load("/LogOnPartial/", { view: "Account" });
    });
</script>
```

And your another page will be;

/views/Extension/LogOn.cshtml:

```
@using netlek.ViewModels.Account
@model LogOnModel

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_NoHeaderLayout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "Log On";
}

<div id="logon-wrap" class="span4">
    // @Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial")
</div>

 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#logon-wrap").load("/LogOnPartial/", { view: "External" });
        });
 </script>
```